# How can I uninstall couchDB?

Tags: macos, couchdb

I've tried deleting the application, but `http://127.0.0.1:5984/` is still accessible. How can I completely remove couchDB?

Comment: Is there a process running? I'm unfamiliar with OS/X, but you may have to kill the CouchDB process as well (which is running in memory)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `ps -U couchdb -o pid= | xargs kill -9` Might kill it and if not it will give you the PID which in my case is

```
kill: 757: Operation not permitted
kill: 767: Operation not permitted
```

Then go to Activity Moniter and locate the PID's and Force Quit.